# Disable clock edit on windows 6.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

i want to disable edit in clock at windows 6.5 .. i have many people in our company edit date and time to abuse ..

so i want to close this case by disable any edit in date&time .. 
..and i searched many times and i didn't find any code

i find this code ..

```
System.Byte[] offValue = new byte[1];
        offValue [0] = 0x30;
        OpenNETCF.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey = 
        OpenNETCF.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Clock\", true);
        registryKey.SetValue("AppState", offValue);
        registryKey.Close();
```

but didn't have OpenNETCF dll or reference to run this code

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Clock App in Windows 6.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839293/disable-clock-app-in-windows-6-5)