# Disable Clock App in Windows 6.5

Tags: c#, xml, clock, windows-mobile-6.5, intermec

Disable Clock App on Windows 6.5

this code run normally in windows 6 .. but didn't work in windows 6.5

PDA (Intermic CN51)

```
System.Byte[] offValue = new byte[1];
offValue[0] = 0x30;
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey =
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Clock\", true);
registryKey.SetValue("AppState", offValue);
registryKey.Close();
```

the (Appstate) registry-key already fired  with 30 value .. but nothing changed in Clock App .. i tried change value but nothing changed in it

i want try XML code but didn't know how i use this

```
       -->
<characteristic type="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun">
  <parm name="1" value="clock.exe" datatype="string" />
</characteristic>
<!--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable a program by policy you need to set the use of the 'blacklist' globally first and then your list of disallowed apps is used:

```
REGEDIT4

;Enable blacklist of applications that should not run
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security\Policies\Shell]
"DisallowRun"=dword:1

;Add entries to blacklist of applications that should not run
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
"1"="fexplore.exe"
"2"="iexplore.exe"
"3"="clock.exe"
```

see also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/03/27/blacklist-applications-to-disable-use/